# LVM for backup and restore

Tags: lvm

Trying to wrap my head around some concepts.

I have installed Ubuntu and tweaked it considerably. The reason I was t to use LVM is to capture some advantages I had with windows and VM along with puppet. When I pooched a nginx config or wanted to try something and it failed - I removed the puppet line and rebuilt VM.

I cant do that on a Ubuntu machine that is also my desktop - so that is where I'd like to use LVM.

I'd like to restore the directories affected by installing a package and it's dependencies.

LVM requires the use of partitions - I think? How do I partition my drives to accomplish the above? A boot partition (can I call it core?) And an apps partition - the latter is what I backup?

How does the apps map to /etc /sbin and so on???

Comment: LVM doesn't really use partitions. You basically pool all your storage together into a volume group and make logical volumes/filesystems out of that pool. Similar to dynamic drives in Windows (broadly speaking). You'll have to use a `/boot` partition but that's because the `grub` bootloader doesn't support lvm so you have a chicken and egg problem. Outside of `/boot` it's all volume groups and logical volumes.

Comment: Although, if this is in a VM, shouldn't you have some sort of snapshot functionality already?

Comment: Its not a VM...I'm running ubuntu as the host so I no longer need windows with a VM running Debian etc

Comment: If you often roll back a filesystem tree, I think zfs or btrfs snapshots will work better than LVM snapshots. But I second Hans-Martin Mosner, uninstalling software by rolling back a directory tree is a bad idea, it only works in highly specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

Rolling back an installation should not be done by restoring the contents of a filesystem, as that will typically affect other installed packages as well. For a lightweight VM alternative, you might want to look at docker, which can be used to separate different userspace environments for different applications. Docker images are built from Makefile-like definitions, probably comparable to puppet (I never worked with that). It's lightweight in that the kernel is shared between the host and guests. Give it a try!

Comment: I've looked into docker but I believe it introduces the same issues as vagrant and puppet might on my windows machine. This idea is similar to a wamp setup but Ubuntu not windows. Netbeans nginx etc all in same space for faster less error prone development. Vagrant has been great but a few key issues force me to reconsider my setup. If I could restore a snapshot to the previous time - I could in effect achieve the same setup/teardown flexibility that a VM offers...I think :)

Comment: If you really want to run a shared system with a kind of global rollback option, you could use btrfs as a filesystem. It gives you even greater flexibility in allocating disk space for different subvolumes and supports volume snapshots. Caveat: the version in Ubuntu has known issues, I've experienced write errors when a snapshot was generated in parallel, and mount problems after a clean shutdown and reboot, so I consider it experimental at this time.

Comment: I have done limited research but rolling back co figuration changes seems to be possible via LVM - so let me ask you - why is it not for my scenario?

Comment: I googled a bit more...found an article or two that do confirm lvm is not an ideal  back up solution. Lvm would be better suited to keeping hourly diff's of a mysql database?